# SpriteKit: Wrong resolution when transition to another Scene

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, scene

When I present a new scene it has a very very low resolution. I have set the resolution correctly in the scene editor. I think it's a bug of XCode7 beta 6. Or made I a mistake?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let view = view {
        let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the scene editor.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/wuw4ugavv/